# Is there a way to select tintColor in Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, tintcolor

If I want, for instance make the background of a button in the tintColor, how can I do it in Interface Builder?
I don't really understand why there isn't a "tintColor" option in all the color choices. 
Perhaps there's something I miss here?

PS: I understand I can do this in code, but if there's something in XCode, I prefer to use it.

Comment: Do you mean changing the tint of a button using interface builder?

Comment: Yes! The button is by default background transparent and text in tintColor, I want it to be background tintColor and text White. I can make the text white, I can change the background color, but I don't see how to make it tintColor.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the Tint option under the attribute inspector. You have to scroll down a bit as it isn't grouped with the text/shadow colour options at the top.

[image: tint option]

This is in XCode 8 but I'm pretty sure I've seen it as an option since at least XCode 6.

Comment: If I understand icorrectly, this option is for changing the color of the tintColor. What I want to do, is make the background the color of the tintColor, whichever it is...  English isn't my native language, I understand that I have trouble explaining it!

Comment: Whoops sorry! I'll look into another solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend the UIButton to implement that. Here is a sample code

```
class ColoredButton: UIButton {
    // MARK: Overrides

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        redraw()
    }

    override public var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private

    private func redraw() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        if self.isEnabled {
            self.backgroundColor = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!?.tintColor
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I am sure i have seen somewhere in Apple apps there was such a colored button. It's in their Human Interface Guidelines too (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/buttons/). But don't know why they didn't implemented it's style with state management in UIKit. BackgroudColor doesn't supports states by default and you would have to implement that if you would like to get maybe a transparency on background when user selects the button. Maybe another way would be to convert UIColor to UIImage because backgroundImage supports states. I'm almost sure it won't be a good idea too:)